# mysql select sum of rows by comparing two relations

Tags: mysql, database

I have data from tests with two lists of parts, called in and out. I need to select SUM of test values for each part after the last test where the part went in but didn't come out.

```
IN LIST                 OUT LIST                 TEST
+--------+-----------+  +--------+------------+  +------+-------+
| testid | in_partid |  | testid | out_partid |  | test | value |
+--------+-----------+  +--------+------------+  +------+-------+
|      1 |        10 |  |      1 |         10 |  |    1 |     1 |
|      1 |        20 |  |      1 |         20 |  |    2 |    10 |
|      2 |        10 |  |      2 |         10 |  |    3 |   100 |
|      2 |        20 |  |        |            |  |      |       |
|      3 |        10 |  |      3 |         10 |  |      |       |
|      3 |        20 |  |      3 |         20 |  |      |       |
+--------+-----------+  +--------+------------+  +------+-------+
```

SUM is pretty straightforward, but can I limit it to those rows where testid is greater than testid for the last inspection where part went in but not out?

In this example, part 10 should SUM all three test values, because it's included in all lists, but part 20 should only return value for test 3, as in test 2 it was not included in both in and out lists.

```
partid  sum(value)
    10        111
    20        100
```

Can I do with with mysql, or do I need to include php in the mix?

Comment: Nested sql queries or php. I'd prefer second one, cause first one may be slow.

Comment: I would loop through each partid to check if they are included in the out list. I can't think of one mysql query that can check all possibilities. I also think you're example falls short because what happens when 2-20 would be in the out list, but 2-10 is not? You would probably need to get the same output but the mysql query needs to be completely different.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Maybe I'll loop through the parts, get the last unmatched test with a null LEFT OUTER JOIN and go on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sample output is incorrect from your logic. I think partid 20 should return 101 as it is present in both lists for both tests 1 and 3. Assuming I'm right in that, this query should return the desired results

```
SELECT in_partid,SUM(value)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT in_partid,inl.testid
    FROM in_list inl
    INNER JOIN out_list outl ON in_partid=out_partid AND inl.testid=outl.testid
    ) as tests_passed
  INNER JOIN tests ON tests_passed.testid=test
GROUP BY in_partid
```

EDIT: based on OP's comment my assumption above was wrong and was actually a requirement. Accordingly here is a query that I think fulfils the requirements:

```
SELECT tests_passed.in_partid,SUM(value)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT inl.in_partid,IFNULL(last_failed_test,0) as last_failed_test
    FROM in_list inl LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT in_partid,MAX(inl.testid) as last_failed_test
        FROM in_list inl
        LEFT JOIN out_list outl ON in_partid=out_partid AND inl.testid=outl.testid
        WHERE outl.testid IS NULL
        GROUP BY in_partid
    ) AS last_passed
    ON inl.in_partid=last_passed.in_partid 
) as tests_passed
INNER JOIN tests ON tests_passed.last_failed_test<test
GROUP BY tests_passed.in_partid
```

This returns the sample results given above for the sample data supplied.

Comment: No, it was correct. I'm only interested in results after the "anomaly". Elegant suggestion, but unfortunately it's not what I need. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Juhani Ok, I've updated my answer to deal with that requirement.